# MYSQL request to display the difference of the rows of two tables and delete duplicate fields taking into account the row id

Tags: mysql, database

There are many examples on stackoverflow that allow you to get the difference between the rows of two tables, but they do not take duplicates into account if I want to get an empty field in case of repetition. I did not find a suitable example. There is a request for example:

```
SELECT Id, username FROM table1
WHERE (Id, username) NOT IN (SELECT Id, username FROM table2)
```

which will output rows from table1, which are not present in table2 taking into account id, but I need that in case of repetition of a row field, the query displays an empty field to compare several columns.

Example Table 1

```
id |  name | surname
--------------------
1  | Jhon  | Zero
2  | Test  | First
3  | Mike  | Second
4  | James | Third
5  | Ivan  | Fourth
6  | Jhon  | Zero
```

Table 2

```
id |  name | surname
--------------------
1  | Jhon  | Test0
2  | JACK  | First
3  | MIKE  | Second3
4  | Jame  | Third4
5  | Evan  | Fourth
6  | Jhon  | Zero
```

SELECT Output Result

```
id |  name | surname
--------------------
1  |       | Zero
2  | Test  | 
3  | Mike  | Second
4  | James | Third
5  | Ivan  | 
6  |       |
```

Those. I need to have duplicate fields equal Null when outputting strings - an empty value, and also everything is case sensitive. Please write how to do this, is it even possible with mysql.

Comment: Are the IDs always the same between corresponding rows in the two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have created your table with a case-sensitive collation, this query will give you the results you want. It uses `CASE` expressions to compare the values from each table, only outputting the value if they are different.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       CASE WHEN t1.name != t2.name THEN t1.name END AS name,
       CASE WHEN t1.surname != t2.surname THEN t1.surname END AS surname
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Output

```
id  name    surname
1   null    Zero
2   Test    null
3   Mike    Second
4   James   Third
5   Ivan    null
6   null    null
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6rTHQRFpTarKSqqKjohEYu/0)

If your tables have a case-insensitive collation, you will need to re-collate the individual values in the query:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       CASE WHEN t1.name COLLATE latin1_general_cs != t2.name COLLATE latin1_general_cs THEN t1.name END AS name,
       CASE WHEN t1.surname COLLATE latin1_general_cs != t2.surname THEN t1.surname COLLATE latin1_general_cs END AS surname
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6rTHQRFpTarKSqqKjohEYu/1)